# Select specific value for all corresponding rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rank

I am trying to get a result set of Top Customers which is ordered by a rank value based on year and total.  Easy, right?

BUT, now I want to specify a year, and have ALL rows for that customer return the rank value for that year.

For example, say I have the following data (rank hardcoded for ease):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 'Customer A' as Cust,'123.45' as Total,'2016' as [year],1 as [rank]
    UNION
    SELECT 'Customer A','123.45','2017',3
    UNION
    SELECT 'Customer B','46.67','2016',2
    UNION
    SELECT 'Customer B','423.45','2017',1
    UNION
    SELECT 'Customer B','123.45','2018',1
    UNION
    SELECT 'Customer C','23.45','2016',3
    UNION
    SELECT 'Customer C','223.45','2017',2
    UNION
    SELECT 'Customer C','23.45','2018',2
) as a
ORDER BY a.[year], a.[rank]
```

[image]

If I specify year 2016, I want to pick the rank value for the year 2016 for each customer, and return that for the customer for each of that customer's rows in the result set - should look like the following:

[image]   =>   [image]

The closest I can manage is the following, but it just NULLs the other cells:

```
DECLARE @RankBy VARCHAR(4) = '2016'

SELECT [Year],
    Cust,
    [Total],
    [rank] = (SELECT a.[rank] WHERE Cust = a.Cust AND [Year] = @RankBy)
FROM
(
    SELECT 'Customer A' as Cust,'123.45' as Total,'2016' as [year],1 as [rank]
    UNION
    SELECT 'Customer A','123.45','2017',3
    UNION
    SELECT 'Customer B','46.67','2016',2
    UNION
    SELECT 'Customer B','423.45','2017',1
    UNION
    SELECT 'Customer B','123.45','2018',1
    UNION
    SELECT 'Customer C','23.45','2016',3
    UNION
    SELECT 'Customer C','223.45','2017',2
    UNION
    SELECT 'Customer C','23.45','2018',2
) as a
ORDER BY a.Cust, a.rank
```

[image]

I know I can do this with a temp table and an update statement, but I'm trying to find a way to do it in a single select statement if possible.

(In case anyone is wondering, this is for an SSRS Report, but I don't see that being relevant here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a Windowed Aggregate over a CASE:

```
MIN(CASE WHEN [Year] = @RankBy THEN a.[rank] END)
OVER (PARTITION BY Cust)
```

Comment: That seems to work perfect!!  I figured there was something simple, I was thinking I might need another "rank"/"partitionby" type statement, but couldn't quite get there.  To be honest, I'm not sure I even quite understand why this works, I'll have to take a few minutes to wrap my head around it.  Thanks much!! :)

Comment: OK, I think I've got it.  MIN doesn't necessarily do anything here, you're just grouping by Customer and picking the value where the year is correct, and then partition by allows it to apply to all the Customers in the group, is that correct?  Brilliant!  Thanks again, I'll select this as the answer once the time constraint is over.

Comment: @sǝɯɐſ: Yep, you could use MAX also, but I thought if you got different ranks by year you might pefer the best one.